# Placeholder in HTML Tag <input /> of type "search" and "button" have different colors

Tags: html, css

Eventhough the same style is applied, the placeholder in the `button` is a little bit darker. Why is that?

```css
.input-field {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: lightgray;
  font-family: 'Montsserat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.5;
  color: darkgray;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Another simple example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <input type="search" class="input-field" placeholder="I am a little bit lighter"></input>
  <input type="button" class="input-field" value="I am a little bit darker"></input>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::placeholder#opaque_text:

> Some browsers (such as Firefox) set the default opacity of placeholders to something less than 100%. If you want fully opaque placeholder text, set opacity to 1.

```
.input-field::placeholder { opacity: 1; color: inherit; }
```

fixes the issue for me (tested in Chrome only, but I suppose FF will behave the same.)

`color: inherit` was also needed, I am guessing a default color gets applied via the user agent stylesheet.

Comment: Still still shows 2 different colors in Chrome tho